# java value recieved from client-server program used in another program

Tags: java, eclipse, client, raspberry-pi2, vlcj

My project looks like: I have a bike speedometer attached to simple bike and connected to Raspberry Pi, which is connected over ethernet cable to laptop.

What I want to do is: Raspberry measure the speed of bike wheel and send this value over ethernet cable to laptop. Laptop now uses recieved value and speed up a video, which is played in VLC.

I have working java program on RPi to measure speed of a wheel, I have a working client (on laptop)-server (on RPi) java program to send values from RPi to laptop, and I have a working java program to control speed of video playing in VLC on laptop.

But my problem is, that I don't know how to use values, recieved from RPi over client-server program, in my program, which control speed of video, playing in VLC.

Down are my codes for client and to control speed of video.

Client code:

```
package player;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {

public static int inputPlayer = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    String accept;
    int input;


    DataInputStream inC = null;
    Scanner sc1 = null;

    Socket s = null;

    try {

        s = new Socket ("169.254.218.194", 1342);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Accept connection!");
        accept = sc.next();
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream (s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(accept);
        //inC = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());


    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    while (true) {
            sc1 = new Scanner (s.getInputStream());
            input = sc1.nextInt();
            if (input > 0) {
                inputPlayer = input;
            }

            System.out.println("I" + input);
            //System.out.println("IP" + inputPlayer);
    }
}

public int getInputPlayer () {
    return this.inputPlayer;
}
}
```

Player code:

```
package player;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

public class Player {

private final JFrame frame;
private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;



public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Player(args);
        }
    });
}

public Player(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    contentPane.add(mediaPlayerComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file:URL");
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().skip(1000);



    client c = new client();
    float i = c.getInputPlayer();

    while (true) {  
        //float i = in.nextFloat();
        //System.out.println(i);


        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().setRate(i);
    }
}
}
```

Everything I want to do is to use variable *inputPlayer* from client class as variable *i* in Player class.

As I have done, Eclipse return me error: **"[000000001ade9eb0] core input error: input control fifo overflow, trashing type=2"**

Thanks for your help.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

- the code in the `client` class (btw, class names should begin with uppercase) is never run. You've put all the code in that class in a main method, which only gets executed if you run the application by choosing that class. Essentially, you have two separate applications here. Even if you were to run them at the same time, it wouldn't help you since one would not have direct access to instances of classes in the other.
- `i` is set only once and never updated inside the loop
- you could turn that main method of the `client` class into an ordinary method, but even then you can't have two `while(true)` loops run at the same time if they are on the same thread.

If handling thread is a bit much for you at this stage, you could try simply combining both classes in one. One loop would scan for incoming data and set the players speed as it came. This might or might not work, depending on how the player itself is implemented, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Huh.. I didn't expect so many problems :) OK, I think I solved them. I also implement new programs, using threads. But now I don't know how to successfully manage the run time of threads. The problem is, that when I start my program, the first thread starts to run, then stops, starts to run second thread and this is running endless. So I have to pause second thread for X ms to make first run and then pause the first  one for X ms to run second one etc.... and I don't know how to do this.